# D lang work with Gtk

Tags: d, dmd, gtkd

I have trouble with `gtk`:

1. I cloned from git: `https://github.com/gtkd-developers/GtkD.git`
2. `make & sudo make install`
3. added `-I/usr/local/include/d` to `/etc/dmd.conf`
4. `dmd main.d`

Code:

```
//main.d 
import gtk.Main;
import gtk.MainWindow;

void main(string[] args)
{

}
```

I get the error:

```
main.d(3): Error: module Main is in file 'gtk/Main.d' which cannot be read
import path[0] = /usr/include/dmd/phobos
import path[1] = /usr/include/dmd/druntime/import
import path[2] = /usr/local/include/d
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the file /usr/local/include/d/gtk/Main.d exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I had the same problem yesterday. For me, Ubuntu automatically slapped file permissions that denied everything for the 'others' group when I manually copied the source files to "/usr/include/dmd/gtkd". I guess the same thing probably happened to you. Quick fix: terminal -> "sudo chmod o=xr /usr/local/include/d". This is assuming that the gtkD source files are actually in your "/usr/local/include/d" directory.